# Android - How to prevent previous view from showing when keyboard goes down?

Tags: android

This really makes my view ugly. I hope someone has the solution.

My activity A navigates to B. In Activity B I have several text fields.
Users may press BACK to hide the keyboard after editing. But it seems like keyboard always goes too fast. When it's going down I can see part of the previous view (A's view). Then B's view covers it.

How can I slow down the speed of dismissing the keyboard or make B's view come down faster?

Comment: Which OS version is this on? And is it device or emulator? I've never seen this.

Comment: I've tested on an HTC API 10 and a Samsung API 14. This is interesting. It happens almost every time when I test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen if the activity has no background to its window. Meaning, the theme has the attribute windowBackground="@null".

To remove or set a background, you can choose a theme that has a background set for the windows (something other than "@null"), or define it programmatically on the onCreate() method by calling getWindow().setBackground()

More information about this setting http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html